# Insert html form templates using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm an angular js newbie, so this might sound trivial.
I'm trying to insert html form templates via a angularjs directive.Its like a user selects a particular form template and that template is then inserted into the page.
Being new to angularjs i have no idea how to achieve this.
Any pointers to implement this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Read the [AngularJS Directive Documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) - specifically, you'll be interested in the `template` and `templateUrl` parameters.

You can write out your template as a string, like `template: '<div>foo</div>'`, or pass in the path to the file containing your html, like `templateUrl: 'partials/mytemplate.html'`.

Comment: Ok thnks for dat.But can u show me some example code to insert some html into a view on click of a button by writing a directive.